# svn apache prevent anonymous read dav_svn.authz

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, svn, mod-dav-svn

So I have gone through about a dozen other threads as well as read the http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html
I feel like I have tried everything, and either there is anonymous read to the repository url, or I loose read and write access with authenticated users. I must be doing something stupid.

dav_svn.authz file :

```
    [MyRepository:/]
    $anonymous =
    name = rw
    * = r
    
    [/]
    * = r
    $anonymous =
    $authenticated = rw
    name = rw
```

my site file:

```
 <Location /repourl>
            DAV svn
            SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Subversion Repository"
            AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
            <IfModule mod_authz_svn.c>
                    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
            </IfModule>
            <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
                    Require valid-user
            </LimitExcept>
    </Location>
```

Overall without * = r my authenticated user cannot read or write, but with * = r there is anonymous access, i.e i can navigate to the url and see it. First question, even when * = r comes first, anonnymous users can not access the root '/' to the repository, but can access "MyRepository" even though they have the same settings? Also why would anonymous get access when "$anonymous =" and "Require valid-user". Basically I just need no anonymous access and RW access for the user.  I have tried about 100 different combinations of things seeing if any of them would work, I just didn't want to post all the different combinations I have tried. any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!!!!

```
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
```

Should be

```
<LimitExcept PROPFIND>
```

propfind will prompt the user for the user name and password instead of just displaying access.